# How can I use the Engine within a SQLAlchemy declarative class?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Lets say I have this `User` in my `user.py` module.  I will use this `User` as part of a larger application.  I will configure the `Engine` (database connection) in the main application module.  But...

What if `User.foo` requires a using an `Engine` or `Session`?  For example, I have a function in the database which takes a user id and I want to call that function inside `foo`.  To do so, I need to use `Engine.execute` or `Session.execute`; but the `Engine` or `Session` hasn't been created yet.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.password = password

    def foo(self, bar):
        """I need an Engine or Session!"""
        pass #....

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`object_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.object_session) class method of `Session` class:

```
def foo(self, bar):
    session = Session.object_session(self)
    #....
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an application-level API to retrieve the database whenever someone calls that method.

When using `collective.lead` to integrate SQLAlchemy with Zope, for example, the database is registered with the Zope Component Architecture as a utility, so whenever I need the session I use a getUtility lookup:

```
db = getUtility(IDatabase, name=u'responsecentre')
session = db.session
```

In this case, the ZCA `getUtility` is the application-specific API to look up the database connection, where sessions are bound to threads.